# How to detect a change in what the screen displays?

Tags: java, rgb

Is it possible to write a program such that when something changes on the screen of your computer, you get some kind of an alert? For example, say that you have a green picture on your screen, and it changes to blue after a few seconds. When the change happens, a sound is played. How would I approach this with Java?

Comment: I highly doubt you could. That would likely require communicating directly with the video adapter that's connected to the display. I don't know if Java could do that, but it certainly wouldn't be efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.awt.Robot` has a method called [`createScreenCapture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) that will give you a BufferedImage of an arbitrary rectangle on the screen. You can take a screen capture every so often and either compare it against the previous capture or monitor it for specific values.

Comment: Just a side note - This method is notoriously slow